# asp.net 5 Error Handler Middleware not catching Dapper exception

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, error-handling

My application is not catching the Dapper exception in the global exception handler middleware. With other types of exceptions it's working fine. The issue is only in the dapper exceptions, which are from database.

Middleware :-

```
    public class ExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Dapper code :-

```
        public async Task<int> ExecuteAsync(string sql, object param = null, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, int expectedRowsEffected = -1, string connection = null)
    {
        connection = connection == null ? ConnectionString : _configuration.GetConnectionString(connection);
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var rowsEffected = await conn.ExecuteAsync(sql, param, commandType: commandType); // error here but not catch by exception handler middleware
            if (expectedRowsEffected > rowsEffected)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Too many rows effected. Expected: {expectedRowsEffected}, Effected: {rowsEffected}");
            }
            return rowsEffected;
        }
    }
```

startup.cs - > Configure method

```
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>(); // register middleware here
```

Comment: Hi @Developerzzz, be sure register the `ExceptionMiddleware` before `app.UseRouting();`.

Comment: yes its register before app.UserRouting();